# Problemas ao usar WebService de Frete dos Correios ERRO[-888]

Tags: php, web-service

Então, eu estava fazendo um teste da WebServie de Frete dos Correios, em que voce da os dados do produto e CEP, e a WebService te devolve o valor do Frete. Porém, quando eu vou testar costuma dar esse erro. [Erro] => -888 [MsgErro] => Não foi encontrada precificação.  ERP-008: Dimensoes nao localizadas ou Dimensoes ultrapassam os limites aceitos para este tipo de objeto(-1)."

Aqui está o código :

```
public function setFreight($nrzipcode)
  {

    $nrzipcode = str_replace('-', '', $nrzipcode);

    $qs = http_build_query([
        'nCdEmpresa'=>'',
        'sDsSenha'=>'',
        'nCdServico'=>'04014',
        'sCepOrigem'=>'09853120',
        'sCepDestino'=>$nrzipcode,
        'nVlPeso'=> '0.900',
        'nCdFormato'=>1,
        'nVlComprimento'=>0.5,
        'nVlAltura'=>0.5,
        'nVlLargura'=>0.5,
        'nVlDiametro'=>0.5,
        'sCdMaoPropria'=>'S',
        'nVlValorDeclarado'=>15.00,
        'sCdAvisoRecebimento'=>'N'
      ]);

      $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx/CalcPrecoPrazo?".$qs);

      echo var_dump($xml);
      exit;

      $result = $xml->Servicos->cServico;



      $this->setnrdays($result->PrazoEntrega);
      $this->setvlfreight(Cart::formatValueToDecimal($result->Valor));
      $this->setdeszipcode($nrzipcode);

      $this->save();

      return $result;



  }
```

Eu fiz um var_dump para ver o erro, e diz isso que postei la em cima. Testei vários valores, mas continua o mesmo erro, já não sei como resolver. Agradeceria muito quem me ajudasse.

Comment: Olhando por alto, os valores das dimensões (ex., `nVlComprimento`) são em centímetros. Vc está passando meio centímetro em cada dimensão, o que me faz pensar que são valores inválidos, pois se cada dimensão tem meio centímetro (`0.5`), dá um pacote quadrado minúsculo, menor que 1 centímetro, o que não é válido. Tente aumentar esses valores (talvez o tamanho de uma caixa de sapato) ou procure no manual dos Correios qual os valores mínimos de um pacote que os Correios aceitam.

Answer (score 1):

Olá.

As dimensões tem que estar dentro desses limites:

MIN - MAX
Comprimento (C): 15 cm – 100 cm
Largura (L): 10 cm – 100 cm
Altura (A): 1 cm – 100 cm
Soma das dimensões (C+L+A): 25 cm – 200 cm

Answer (score -1):

Veja a documentação em https://www.correios.com.br/a-a-z/pdf/calculador-remoto-de-precos-e-prazos/manual-de-implementacao-do-calculo-remoto-de-precos-e-prazos/view

Para cada tipo de envio existe dimensões mínimas, ajuste o seu código com if básico verificando se a dimensão for menor que a minima requerida ele seta a dimensão para o esse valor.